# How to pass default value to a variable in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, ubuntu-14.04, logical-operators

I have written this piece of code to move one directory to another.
What I want with this code is as follows:

1. User will give a file name or a directory name.
2. User may give a destination folder. If user doesn't want a destination folder he/she will just press enter.
3. Then source directory will be copied to destination directory(if given) or a default directory(if destination not given)

Here is the code.

```
$source_folder
$destination_folder
$destination
read -r directory_source
read -r destination_folder
if [ "$destination_folder" = ""]
then
    $destination = "/var/www/html/"
else
    $destination = "$destination_folder"
fi
cp -a "$source_folder" "$destination"
```

Here is the input to this program:

```
Myfiles.sh (called the shell script in terminal)
Max Sum (This is the source directory)
(Pressed enter i.e. No destination given)
```

It gives following error:

```
/usr/local/myfiles/copyDirToHTML.sh: line 6: [: : unary operator expected
/usr/local/myfiles/copyDirToHTML.sh: line 10: =: command not found
cp: cannot stat ‘’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Scripts which require interactive input are less useful because they cannot be incorporated into bigger scripts as building blocks and you forego the useful interactive features of the shell such as tab expansion etc. A sensible `cpd` (for copy with default) would be as simple as `cpd () { cp "$1" "${2-/path/to/default}"; }`

Comment: Thank you, I am just learning. Will try your solution. @tripleee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem

Change

```
if [ "$destination_folder" = ""]
```

to

```
if [ "$destination_folder" = "" ]
```

and change `read -r directory_source`
to

```
read -r source_folder
```

Also you can use the below script. Passing arguments from cmd line

```
#!/bin/sh
source_folder=$1

if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    destination=$2
else
    destination="/var/www/html/"
fi

cp -a "$source_folder" "$destination"
```

Where `$#` is the number of arguments to the script.
$1 - > first argument...Similarly $2..

To run

```
./script.sh source_folder [destination]
```

destination is optional

Comment: I have followed the first instruct you given. Added a space before "]" in if statement. But it throws the following error when giving nothing for destination.

"/usr/local/myfiles/copyDirToHTML.sh: line 8: =: command not found
cp: cannot stat ‘’: No such file or directory"

Comment: Thank you, got it. Though I also got the problem with my code. And added it below.

Comment: There must not be spaces around the `=` in variable assignments! Also the `$` sign in front of the variable name is an error in an assignment. `destination=${destination_folder:-/var/www/html/}` [parameter expansion with defaults](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) would do the same without `if ... else`

Comment: @mata. Thanks for info. I almost missed that. Updated my answer.

Comment: There is a specific syntax so you don't need an explicit default. Look at the `"${variable=value}"` and `"${variable-value}"` parameter substitutions.

Comment: You didn't fix the superfluous dollar sign in the assignment. That's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution to this problem.
The working code is like this:

```
$source_folder
$destination_folder
read -r source_folder
read -r destination_folder
if [ "$destination_folder" = "" ]; then
   sudo cp -a "$source_folder" "/var/www/html/"
else
   sudo cp -a "$source_folder" "$destination_folder"
fi
```

Comment: The empty variable interpolations at the beginning of the script are not only superfluous; they could become syntax errors if these variables could ever be set when the script starts.